# django admin adding hash to image name

Tags: python, django, django-models

Not a duplicate- django admin is adding 7 digit hashes each time I upload an image in admin. I tried what the other post suggests, and I flushed my database and completely restarted. Each new pic I add after completely clearing the database adds a silly hash like "images/profile-medium_J3mKGug.png".

```
class GenericImage(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    image       = models.FileField(upload_to="images/")
    created     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    width       = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    height      = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    category    = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True)
```

and admin.py

```
class GenericImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display    = ["__unicode__", "title", "created", "thumbnail"]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()`

admin.site.register(GenericImage, GenericImageAdmin)
```

it is giving my bad filenames even on the first time loading this pic after clearing my db

Comment: The problem isn't that you need to flush your database: it's that you need to flush your media folder.  If you've already uploaded a file called 'profile-medium.png', that's still in the media folder even if the django model/db entry is gone.

Comment: I bet that'll work...I never modified media/images and now there's like 15 built up, with duplicates. I'll try the solution tonight when I get home...thanks Brizzle

Comment: @MBrizzle are you suggesting I delete them all by hand, or do I need to always clear my cache too when this happens? And I started by uploading the photos directly TO the media/images dir, as in right when I downloaded them off Google, should I start with these images somewhere on my machine and upload them normally through django admin (so I can have the title, created_at, and user fields and whatnot populated), will adding them through django admin automatically throw them into the media/images folder? if not, how do I set that up?

Comment: Wow, I moved them all into a tmp folder on desktop, and adding from django admin shows no problems. @MBrizzle thanks Mr. Brouch, and nice art

Comment: Glad it worked! I actually wrote a simple shell script for myself to clear the contents of my media folder, because I ended up having to do it so often.